# MongoDB: Sort if value is present in array or not

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

question: I have a document where a field picked_by_ids is an array of all user ids. Now I have to sort this table such that if provided id is there in picked_by_ids then it should come at top and all other records should list after that.

Note: We may have a large table and need to add indexing for this. Also need to add pagination.

Thanks.